# Angular reactive form two way binding

Tags: angular, angular-ngmodel, angular-reactive-forms, two-way-binding

I'm having trouble deciding what is the best way for Angular reactive-form two way data_binding.
I want to have an ngmodel on my input, in the form in order to work with a directive that use the model. But in order to do that, I have to work with two objects like so:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <input name="first" formControlName="first" [(ngModel)]="example.first"/>
  <input name="last" formControlName="last" [(ngModel)]="example.last"/>
</form>

export class App {
  form: FormGroup;
  example = { first: '', last: '' };

  constructor(builder: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = builder.group({
      first: '',
      last: ''
    })
  }
}
```

1. the example
2. the form it self

and it complex my code.

what is the best way?

Comment: Not a good idea mixing reative and template driven approaches, if you want to use `ngModel` use template driven forms instead

Comment: Why would you need ngModel if you are already using reactive form? As mentioned, choose either tempate driven or reactive form :)

Comment: Some of my directive uses the model as I wrote. Should I just stop working with the modal on my directives?

Comment: Well, based on your requirements, choose either approach, mixing them both is not recommended, also based on your Angular version you should get a deprecation warning about using them together. Hard to tell anything more, since not knowing the whole picture. You can assign the value of `example` to the formcontrols (so remove the ngModel), but as said, not knowing the whole extent of your code it's hard to advice more based on what all you need `example` for.